# Uneeded session info at the end of url

Tags: php, session, curl

We have a forums crawling engine. When I crawl some links using curl its adds a variable in the url as such s=23423235sdfsd234

e.g. `forum.com/displayforum?php?f=34`

would become `forum.com/displayforum?php?f=34s=23423235sdfsd234`

Normally surfing the forum the urls are there without the s=blabla. I believe this is the session number added to the url automatically. Is there anyway to avoid this as we are getting duplicates in our database for the same url.

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `session.use_only_cookies` in php.ini...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies

You can also do it in PHP...

```
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
```